# Web Service Development Lifecycle

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Working with Eclipse and WebLogic.

I'm making a diagram (**approximately**) about the arquitecture and implementation of a web service, something like this:

[image]

but more extensive. So I wrote some steps I followed to make a SOAP WS (after a lot of Google search), however there are things I don't understand yet.

1. Create Dynamic Web Project, importing necessary libs, Web App libraries (like axis, jaxrpc, wsdl4j, saaj.  `I read is the most common way because it has generic config`
2. Create ServiceExample.java with methods you need.
3. Right click on ServiceExample.java/New/Web Service
4. Choose Web service

   - Type:

     - Bottom up: to create ws from java classes
     - Top down: to create java classes from wsdl,
   - Implementation and
   - Level (I select 'start'):

     - Develop: will create the service code `a)What code? Where? Isn't the same of step 2?`
     - Assemble: this ensures that the project that will host the Web service or client gets associated to an EAR when required by the target application server `ok`
     - Deploy: will create the deployment code for the service `b)what code? where?`
     - Install: will install the service on the chosen server `ok`
     - Start: **will start the server** once the service has been installed on it `ok`
     - Test: will provide various options for testing the service `I use an ws client so don't need`
5. Open the url http://url:to/myWebService?wsdl in a web browser and copy it, an xml file should appear. The url/access configuration is in web.xml in the project.

   - if error 403: some error in the configurations files
   - if error 404: url/path not found
6. Create new Dynamic Web Project for the client

   - Right click on src folder or package / New / Web Service Client / Paste WSDL url / choose client level generation `c)same questions`
   - New files appeared: ServiceExample.java, ServiceExampleProxy.java, ServiceExampleService.java, ServiceExampleServiceLocator.java, ServiceExampleSoapBindingStub.java `d) What does each class do?`
   - `e)Is the client the same as making a Web App (java classes/servelts + jsp files)?`
7. Access Web service client in web browser and test a method
8. `f)By some process I don't understand` the client send a request (by xml) and arrives to the web service. It gives response back with requested data.

I get it working but I'm stuck learning this structure/process. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant **approximately**, but to be clear, the panorama  can variate depending on the technologies,frameworks & others that are being used.
I will improve this exact diagram when I can.
[image: Example diagram web service life cycle]

Comment: nothing exists in the link provided. Please fix the link so others can see the answer.

Comment: @Agent47 Updated.